# checking if values in both foreach is equal and displaying accordingly giving error in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement, foreach

i have two arrays which in which i am using foreach for them to display the result, here what i want is to check if id in the 1st array is present in the second, if not present then display them, i did the following code:

```html
    foreach($name as $n){

            foreach($response as $r){

            if ($n->id != $r->cid) {
      
      
      echo $n->id;
      
      }
      }
      }
```

here the issue is if only one values is equal then its coming fine, but if 2 values are equal then all the results are displayed 2 times, like that if 3 then the results are displayed  times and so on. can anyone please tell me how to fix this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it :

```
$tmpIds = [];
foreach($name as $n){
    foreach($response as $r){
        if ($n->id != $r->cid) {
            if(!in_array($n->id, $tmpIds)){
                $tmpIds[] = $n->id;
                echo $n->id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Example](https://onlinephp.io?s=hVBLCoMwEF1H8A4jCBrQRd22WrrsGURKjBFT8EPiphTv3kn8tBRsAwm8eZ955HQemsF1_I61IoXcdUjYl3fBR3pRij1CHASyCiDN4BAZYIQWBixATKNfluTLUv637G4pjlhTCT30nd6tyteU_T2rJDGSJXZsh2ulAVMNrHslGG9C-ynANPgdfboO4NmotYil1UqbI2tAZ5zJCrwUuTjDjRQ-FETWoSe7G7OdZm0ESwlqssgmXaZ5geVmJRYklieCN_17uFkmIzAP3ukF&v=8.1.6)

Comment: i tried this but have an issue, if there is only 1 duplicate value its coming fine, but if its more than 1 duplicate value all the values are getting displayed

Comment: can you create a example with that case on https://onlinephp.io/ and share !?

Comment: can u please create a chat here

Comment: In my example, it has case duplicate id.

Comment: actually i have 2 database tables, i want to compare them and display values from table1 which are not present in table 2

Comment: I 'm driving, wait for me about 2 hours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245259/discussion-between-xupitan-and-zno).